# graphics.py and python - looking for help on button clicking - bound motion

Tags: python, button, graphics, zelle-graphics

I am working on a couple ideas here:

1. hovering over a button changes the colour (using cursor binding) - works fine
2. when clicked, the button changes colour - issues with this

If the user is hovering over the button, the button changes colour. The first time it works, and then if the user click anywhere OUTSIDE of the button, the button changes colour.  Any ideas?

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin("button", 500, 500)
win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)

def motion(event):
    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    if (x1 > 10 and x1 < 80) and (y1 > 20 and y1 < 80):
        rectangle1.setFill("red")        
        if win.getMouse():
            rectangle1.setFill("blue")
            print("Clicked")
    else:
        rectangle1.setFill("white")

win.bind('<Motion>', motion)

rectangle1 = Rectangle(Point(10, 20), Point(80, 80))
rectangle1.draw(win)
win.mainloop()
```

EDIT :
I found a slight workaround, but it is doesn't feel like it is workable for a game or even menu.  It works as long as the mouse is completely still when you click on it. As I said, I am sure there are ways to make this better so any help is appreciated.

```
from graphics import *
import time
win = GraphWin("buttons", 500, 500)
win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)

def motion(event):
    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    if (x1 > 10 and x1 < 80) and (y1 > 20 and y1 < 80):
        rectangle1.setFill("red")
    else:
        rectangle1.setFill("white")
    click = win.getMouse()
    if (click.getX()>10 and click.getX()<80) and (click.getY()>20 and click.getY()<80):
        rectangle1.setFill("blue")
        print("Clicked")

win.bind('<Motion>', motion)

rectangle1 = Rectangle(Point(10, 20), Point(80, 80))
rectangle1.draw(win)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe you should bind function to event `<Button1>` to catch left mouse button click

Comment: it should have events `<Enter>` for hovering` and `<Leave>` for unhovering

Answer (score 0):

In `motion` I would use use global variable

```
    global hovered

    hovered = (10 < x1 < 80) and (20 < y1 < 80)
```

And I would use `<Button-1>` to run function when mouse (left-button) was clicked. And it would check if `hovered` is `True`

```
from graphics import *

# --- functions ---

def motion(event):
    global hovered
    
    hovered = (10 < event.x < 80) and (20 < event.y < 80)
        
    if hovered:
        rectangle1.setFill("red")
        print("Hovered")
    else:
        rectangle1.setFill("white")
        print("UnHovered")
        
def click_left_button(event):
    if hovered:
        rectangle1.setFill("blue")
        print("Clicked Left")

def click_right_button(event):
    if hovered:
        rectangle1.setFill("black")
        print("Clicked Right")

# --- main ---

hovered = False

win = GraphWin("buttons", 500, 500)
#win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)

win.bind('<Motion>', motion)
win.bind('<Button-1>', click_left_button)
#win.bind('<Button-2>', click_middle_button)
win.bind('<Button-3>', click_right_button)

rectangle1 = Rectangle(Point(10, 20), Point(80, 80))
rectangle1.draw(win)

win.mainloop()
```

But I don't know if this resolve all problems. Because when you keep press button then it sets `BLUE` but if I move then change color to `RED` but it should keep this color until I release button. It may need to use `<ButtonPress-1>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>`

---

**EDIT:**

it seems this works like real button

```
from graphics import *

# --- functions ---

def motion(event):
    global previous 
    global hovered
    
    hovered = (10 < event.x < 80) and (20 < event.y < 80)
        
    if not clicked:
        if hovered:
            if not previous:
                rectangle1.setFill("red")
                print("Enter")
        else:
            if previous:
                rectangle1.setFill("white")
                print("Leave")
                
    previous = hovered
    
def press_left_button(event):
    global clicked

    if hovered:
        clicked = True
        rectangle1.setFill("blue")
        print("Pressed Left")

def release_left_button(event):
    global clicked

    if clicked:    
        clicked = False
        print("Released left")
    
    if hovered:
        rectangle1.setFill("red")
    else:
        rectangle1.setFill("white")
        
# --- main ---

previous = False
hovered = False
clicked = False

win = GraphWin("buttons", 500, 500)
#win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)

win.bind('<Motion>', motion)
win.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', press_left_button)
win.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', release_left_button)

rectangle1 = Rectangle(Point(10, 20), Point(80, 80))
rectangle1.setFill("white")
rectangle1.draw(win)

win.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If I put code in class `Button` then I can simply create many buttons

[image]

```
from graphics import *

# --- classes ---

class Button():
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        
        self.x1 = x
        self.y1 = y
        self.x2 = x + w
        self.y2 = y + w
        
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        
        self.rectangle = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x+w, y+h))
        self.rectangle.setFill("white")
    
        self.previous = False
        self.hovered = False
        self.clicked = False
        
    def draw(self, win):
        self.rectangle.draw(win)
        
    def on_motion(self, event):
        self.hovered = (self.x1 < event.x < self.x2) and (self.y1 < event.y < self.y2)
        
        if not self.clicked:
            if self.hovered:
                if not self.previous:
                    self.rectangle.setFill("red")
                    #print("Enter")
            else:
                if self.previous:
                    self.rectangle.setFill("white")
                    #print("Leave")
                
        self.previous = self.hovered

    def on_press_left_button(self, event):
        self.clicked
    
        if self.hovered:
            self.clicked = True
            self.rectangle.setFill("blue")
            #print("Pressed Left")
    
    def on_release_left_button(self, event):
        self.clicked
    
        if self.clicked:    
            self.clicked = False
            #print("Released left")
        
        if self.hovered:
            self.rectangle.setFill("red")
        else:
            self.rectangle.setFill("white")
            
# --- functions ---

def motion(event):
    for button in all_buttons:
        button.on_motion(event)
    
def press_left_button(event):    
    for button in all_buttons:
        button.on_press_left_button(event)
        
def release_left_button(event):    
    for button in all_buttons:
        button.on_release_left_button(event)

# --- main ---

win = GraphWin("buttons", 500, 500)
#win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)

win.bind('<Motion>', motion)
win.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', press_left_button)
win.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', release_left_button)

all_buttons = []

for y in range(10, 400, 60):
    for x in range(10, 400, 60):
        button = Button(x, y, 50, 50)
        button.draw(win)
        all_buttons.append( button )

win.mainloop()
```